# getNodeText() does not return text for object manager search tree

Tags: treeview, sap-gui, silktest

I see the following search tree in SAP GUI:

[image: SAP object manager search tree]

I'm trying to verify the contents of that tree, mainly I want to get the text that is displayed for the nodes. I'm using [getNodeText() [MicroFocus]](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FGetNodeTextMethodSapTree_ref.html) to get the text of the node, but it returns an empty string for all nodes.

As an alternative, I tried [getItemText() [MicroFocus]](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FGetItemTextMethodSapTree_ref.html) with `"HierarchyHeader"` as the `itemName` parameter. Still no luck.

So from Silk4J point of view, the tree looks like this, which makes it impossible to identify the nodes:

[image: SAP object manager search tree from Silk4J]

I even tried to identify nodes using the icon returned by [getNodeAbapImage() [MicroFocus]](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FGetAbapImageMethodSapTree_ref.html), but this also returns an empty string.

For now I don't have any chance to identify the nodes in the search tree. Is there a way to get the node text? A workaround is also acceptable.

I am using Silk4J 15.5 Hotfix 5 (15.5.5.7099).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the SAP script recorder to see what script it generates when I click some nodes and the following was recorded:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/...").selectItem "          2","&Hierarchy"
```

Then I tried to use `"&Hierachy"` instead of `"HierarchyHeader"` in `getItemText()`and it worked.

Next, I figured out where the text `"&Hierarchy"` comes from so that I don't have a hard-coded magic constant. I found that it is `getColumnNames().get(0)`. Since the tree type is `COLUMN` with only one column displayed, the index should always be `0`.

Since `getNodeText()` works for some other trees in SAP, I have implemented the following fallback strategy:

```
@Override
public String getNodeText(String nodeKey)
{
    String nodeText = tree.getNodeText(nodeKey);
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(nodeText))
    {
        nodeText = getItemText(nodeKey, tree.getColumnNames().get(0));
    }
    return nodeText;
}
```